# Paraphrasing through NLP algorithms

Tags: algorithm, nlp

There are some text spinner tools that paraphrase a given text. However, they are not best because they produce text that is not very readable and therefore, not good for search engines. Is there a way to combine multiple algorithms to obtain a more robust paraphrasing algorithm?

Comment: What algorithms / tools have you looked into, so far? Why didn't they satisfy you? Which language do you actually want to paraphrase?

Comment: I am new to this. One of the NLP algorithms that I have worked with so far is LSI. 
I prefer to work with python, however other languages are also OK. Any clue is appreciated.
(If by language you meant text language, it is English.)

Comment: You can try gpt2 language model for paraphrasing